# div and image do not show in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html

I have a web page where I make an ajax call on click in a button and once I click the button it pop up a .gif image. Bellow code I have used to do this

HTML

```
<div class="overlay" id="enrollMeLoading" style="display:none">
    <img src="~/Images/loading.gif" style="width: 6%; margin-left: 43%; margin-top: 25%;" />
</div>
```

Jquery: on a button clicked this image must be shown up

```
$('#enrollMeLoading').show();
```

This functionality is working in Firefox but when I try it in Chrome it does not show the image.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: can you please share a jsfiddle link of your problem statement?

Comment: Try `&#126` for the `~`.

Comment: Similar code works for me, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/90ssvnry/)

Answer (score 2):

try this
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xh7we9xm/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="show imgae" />

<div class="overlay" id="enrollMeLoading" >
    <img src="~/Images/loading.gif" style="width: 6%; margin-left: 43%; margin-top: 25%;" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#enrollMeLoading  {
    border:1px solid #f00;
    min-height:200px;
}

#enrollMeLoading img {
    border:1px solid #f00;
    min-height:200px;
    display:none;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click',function(){
        $('#enrollMeLoading img').css('display','block');    
    }) 
})
```

Note: You cannot give show to the current element, separate button has to be created

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in onclick of button.

```
     $('#enrollMeLoading').show();                           
          setTimeout(function(){
//Make your ajax call here
    }, 100);
```

In this case the gif shows up and then ajax call happens. if u make ajax call just next to show statement then the gif does not show up most of the times.